# How to get number of begin transactions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In Microsoft MSSQL, `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` method is available to get number of BEGIN TRANSACTION statements.

What is the equivalent command in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A_horse_with_no_name's comment had me curious, and it seems like PostgreSQL doesn't use **transactions** in the same way that you're used to in Microsoft SQL Server. Rather they use **Save Points**. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36471735/5059085) gives a little context about **Save Points** and how to track them (see the comments on the answer for additional details).

There typically can only be one **transaction** open at a time, but you can achieve *nested transactions* utilizing [**save points**](https://programmer.help/blogs/nested-transaction-of-postgresql-transaction-feature.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it true that it is not possible to keep track number of SavePoints based on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75474/in-postgres-how-to-get-a-list-of-current-defined-savepoint? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is `xact_commit` same as `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT`? The https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/monitoring-stats.html states that `xact_commit` returns number of transactions in this database that have been committed. I wonder if both methods are similar? Please advise!

Comment: @hunterex Unfortunately I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL but I believe that the StackOverflow question you linked is correct. And `xact_commit` is different because it tracks the total number of `commit`s made in the database. `@TRANCOUNT` is the number of active transactions (which will inevitably return to 0 when the transaction either rollback or all of the active transactions get committed).